# Cannot log into backend after 'referenceindex:update'

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

I wanted to update my TYPO3 installation from 9.5.1 to 10.4.9.

[This page](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/Upgrade/UpdateReferenceIndex/Index.html) says to execute `php ./typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 referenceindex:update` on the shell. I did that and got this exception:

```
Error in GnuTLS initialization: Failed to acquire random data.

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception An exception occurred in driver: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
thrown in file /is/htdocs/XXX/typo3/typo3-9.5.1/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
in line 112
```

When I try to log back into the backend I now get these errors in the browser console:

```
require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1 GET http://XXX/typo3/TYPO3/CMS/Backend/Login.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Error: Script error for "TYPO3/CMS/Backend/Login"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1)
require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1 GET http://XXX/typo3/TYPO3/CMS/Backend/UserPassLogin.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Error: Script error for "TYPO3/CMS/Backend/UserPassLogin"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1)
GET http://XXX/typo3/TYPO3/CMS/Rsaauth/RsaEncryptionModule.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Error: Script error for "TYPO3/CMS/Rsaauth/RsaEncryptionModule"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require-d5051a72d474f75e61b6d2ad78818898.js:1)
```

The installation is hosted on a Host Europe webspace.

Configuration is:

- Operating system: Unix
- PHP version: 7.2.34-he.0
- PHP CGI detected: No
- DB Version: MySQL 5.7.30

Comment: Can you access the TYPO3 Install Tool at yourdomain.tld/typo3/install.php? There you can check if there are errors in your environment, if the database connection works fine and you can flush all caches.

Comment: Another thing you should try, since the error message is about rsaauth: Try to set `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['loginSecurityLevel'] = 'normal';` in your LocalConfiguration.php. The TYPO3 core module rsaauth has been removed in TYPO3 v10 anyway since everybody is expected to use SSL anyway.

Comment: @PeterKraume I can access the Install tool. After flushing the cache and clicking some other buttons that seemed useful I can log into the backend again. Thank you!